# facebook like button decreases the count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, social-media

I am using the facebook like button

```
<fb:like href="My URL" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
```

and yesterday it was 119 and today it's 90 and it happens with lots of other pages 
i don't have an explanation to tell to the business team as they think that it's our problem.

i tried to search about how does facebook do retrieving the count or what happened makes it decreasing the count but i found nothing.

would anybody help me why is this happening, or how to fix ...

Comment: Is it possible that the people who had originally liked it proceeded to unlike it?

Comment: yea sure, but the business can't get convenced by this. :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding out the actual count using the fql

example : $fql = "SELECT share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='MYURL'";
$response = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' =>$fql,));
print_r($response);

You will get the actual count